Can we use Preemptive Resource with a Container in simpy?
I'm working on a simulation working with simpy where i've a class like this:
class memory:
    def __init__(self, env: Environment, size: int, memory_name: str):
        """Instantiation function

        Args:
        env (Environment): simpy environment
        size (int): Size of memory
        """
        self.is_accessed = PreemptiveResource(env, 1)
        self.container: Container = Container(env, size, size)
    



My goal is to access the variable self.container with some priority but i don't want to block the other process to try accessing it.
By that i mean. I'll have several process with level 1,2 or 3 of priority. which can access the container. And it's only when the process ask for too much that i'd need to prioritize.
If i block the access with :
with self.is_accessed.request(my_prioritie, True) as access:
    self.container.get(value)

It block also another process to access the container even if there is still place in the container.
Do you see other ways?

sounds like you need a broker to manage everything.  When a request comes in the broker can check if there is enough resource for the request and skip any pending requests.  When resources change, but not enough to fill the highest priority request, the broker can then check if other requests can be filled.  In a broker, you can make the matching logic as complicated as you want.  One thing to watch out for is if your small requests keep stealing resources, your big request may never get filled.

I see what you mean, but in my execution, simpy is handling all the time processing. I don't have any time information at all. I guess the best way i could describe what i'm looking for is a PriorityContainer.
Because with the broker, i don't know when other request are being done to the container
